# Use filter only if it its function parameter

Tags: r

I created a function like this

```
load_data <- function(
   data_frame
) {
  result <-
    tbl("database", "table") %>%
    filter(id %in% !!data_frame$id) %>%
    collect()

return(result)
}

# Use
df <- data.frame(id = c(1))
test <- load_data(data_frame = df)
```

I'm curious if there is a way how to do not use filter step in case that I will function like this `test <- load_data()`

Please keep in mind that my real function uses several parameters, not only that data_frame parameter

Comment: Is this `sparkR` or `sparklyr`?

Comment: Can't you just use something like `if (missing(data_frame))` at the beginning of the function to solve this base case?